# Select different columns from joined tables

Tags: mysql

How do I select the id, user_id specifically from the comments table and how do I select username, date, posts from the users table specifically?

here is the code.

```
SELECT users.*, comments.*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.id, c.user_id, u.username, u.date, u.posts 
    FROM comments c, users u 
    WHERE [something]
```

Comment: Note the c and u after comments and users; those declare "aliases" for the tables, which makes referring to them easier.

Comment: It's called an alias. It allows you to shorten the name of the table when used in your query, or to have two calls to the same table that have different aliases.

Comment: Insert a witty comment about feeding a man or teaching him to fish here. :(

Answer (score 1):

Heres a good reference for you [MySQL SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT id, user_id FROM comments";
"SELECT username, date, posts FROM users";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use join, Dan's answer would result to cartesian product (i.e. table comma table) if you inadvertently forgot to put the joining condition in WHERE clause

```
SELECT c.id, c.user_id, u.username, u.date, u.posts 
FROM comments c join users u using(user_id)
WHERE [something]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I suppose you don't know what to put in the `WHERE [something]` in the other answers.

```
SELECT c.id, c.user_id, u.username, u.date, u.posts 
FROM comments c, users u 
WHERE c.user_id = u.id
```

Assuming the user id field in `users` table is called `id`.

You could use also:

```
SELECT c.id, c.user_id, u.username, u.date, u.posts 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.user_id = u.id
```

Anyways, this will solve your problem but I would recommend some MySQL (or SQL in general) readings like [MySql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/)